# Rings with countably generated ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

We know that a commutative ring $R$ with 1 is noetherian if and only if every ideal of $R $ is finitely generated. Now I want to know if the rings whose ideals are countably generated are important, or is there any references for them?